# What "UIViewController" class really does?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I was working in the ViewController.swift and noticed that when I open it, it declares a UIViewController class. I was wondering if that is a new class or an already declared class that we can add code to.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if that is a new class or an already declared class that we can add code to.

`UIViewController` is a class defined in the UIKit framework. It's the class that's used as the base class for all other view controllers in iOS applications, so it provides the behaviors that are expected of any view controller as well as a number of methods that are meant to be overridden. The usual way to "add code" is to create your own subclass of `UIViewController`, which is exactly what you're doing in the ViewController.swift file.

You're going to run across many classes that have the `UI` prefix, and you can look up any of them in the documentation that comes with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController is not the class that you can add code to. But ViewController is default class that has UIViewController as a parent.

ViewController class is already connected with storyboard view controller  when you create your project by default. So you can add some code to ViewController class and connect your UI controls (buttons, labels and so on) with you ViewController class and add some functionality to it.

So yes, you can add some code to it and see what happens when you build and run the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Its a class that manages view controller functions.

For example, "YourClass:UIViewController" means that You extend from UIViewControllerClass, so You are able to use all the functions from mother class, but also add new in "YourClass".